# Calling a function from public static class

Tags: c#, asp.net, static-methods

I am new to ASP.NET.

I really need help on this one since I am stuck.  I've done a lot of reading on google and couldn't figure what I did wrong.

> Error: CS0103: The name 'MyClass' does not exist in the current context

I have a MyClass.cs file, which I like to reuse that function in this file on any pages.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public static class MyClass
    {

        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //

        public static string FormatDateNoTime(string input)
        {
            string thedate;
            DateTime strDate = DateTime.Parse(input);
            thedate = strDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
            return thedate;
        }

        public static string test()
        {
            return "1234";
        }

    }
}
```

Another Page2.aspx.cs call this function, but err

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

using MyNameSpace;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write(MyClass.FormatDateNoTime("02/01/2012"));
    }
}
```

Can someone plese help, I simply just want to reuse this function in any pages.

Comment: Have you removed the namespace in which the `_Default` class should be in or is it just a copy/paste mistake?

Comment: where did you declare your class? is it in the App_Code or where?

Comment: Yes, the MyClass.cs I created is in the App_Code folder.

Comment: I Implemented your code in a sample project and its working absolutely fine. Try to clean and rebuild your solution.

Comment: Also watch your output window.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestions

- You need to import the namespace of `MyClass` by including `using namespaceOfMyClass` or both caller class and the class being called should belong to the same namespace
- Sometimes the class is not compiled by default. Right-click the file in the solution explorer and click properties. Check the `Build Action` properties and make sure it says "Compile"
- Build your project from the topmost level e.g. Solution

Comment: This is where I was stuck also.  I Right-Click the file in the Solution Explore, select Properies. There is only two options there, one is FileName = "MyClass.cs" and other is Full Path = "The Path", I don't see any Build Action or Compile option. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

in this:

```
Response.Write(MyClass.FormatDateNoTime("02/01/2012"));
```

right click on `MyClass` and choose "resolve", which should contain an option to either add the namespace or to use the fully qualified name of the type.

If resolve is not present, add a reference to the assembly that contains MyClass.cs from the assembly that contains Page2.aspx.cs.

Comment: This sounds like the problem I'm having "If resolve is not present, add a reference to the assembly".  Can you please show me how to? sorry I an mew.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I resolved the problem with restarting of VS. After restar the cs-file with problematic class was not visible in my project. I added the file again to the project in the solution explorer and built the complete project.